# setup a background timer thread that runs within the IIS of ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I want to know how to setup a background  timer  thread that runs within the  IIS 7.5 of  ASP.NET 4 application . This  thread  should start when application has started and this thread should periodically scan the database  to send escalation emails or alert (through SignalR hosted in same IIS server) using the business logic layer.

I am completly new on this topic, Can anyone throw some light on how to setup timer thread in IIS to achive above requirment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz Scheduler to send escalation mails with the help of scheduler [QuartZ Scheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

```
// construct a scheduler factory
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();

// construct job info
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(HelloJob));
// fire every hour
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeHourlyTrigger();
// start on the next even hour
trigger.StartTimeUtc = TriggerUtils.GetEvenHourDate(DateTime.UtcNow);  
trigger.Name = "myTrigger";
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

Comment: Ravi- I dont know how "QuartZ Scheduler" will help in this scenario because I am looking for an approach to setup an asp.net mvc app that should scan db and send alert through my own program (email component) so basically i want to setup a mvc app in IIS to run certain intervals using iis features without using any additional open source/tools.

Answer (score 0):

> , Can anyone throw some light on how to setup timer thread in IIS to achive above requirment?

In general it's not a good idea to attempt to do something like this in a IIS app.  Your AppDomain can be stopped for many reasons (after a period of inactivity, when exceeding memory thresholds, on a configurable schedule), and typically won't be started again until a request is received.

Instead, use some other way to schedule your required task - e.g. Windows Task Scheduler.  Your scheduled task can be very simple, perhaps just a script that sends a request to your IIS application, which will be started if it isn't running, and can then perform the necessary work.

E.g. you could schedule a VBScript script that does something like:

```
url = ... some url in your application that sends escalation emails ...
set http = CreateObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
http.open "GET",url,false
http.send
htmlpage = http.responsetext 
WScript.Echo htmlpage
```

**UPDATE** in response to comment

> I understand the risk of setup in IIS (app domain recycle) but there is a restriction on using window service/schedule as per client requirement. so i am looking for the technical details to done in IIS itself.

If you understand the risks, you can simply have a static Timer that is started from Application_Start in global.asax. Each time the timer fires, do your stuff.

Comment: Joe - I understand the risk of setup in IIS (app domain recycle) but there is a restriction on using window service/schedule as per client requirement. so i am looking for the technical details to done in IIS itself.